# Sequelize js query through hasMany relationship

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js, pg

UPDATED :::: I am trying to return a list of Users based on a search term I am receiving from the client.  User hasMany Skills. I would like to return all users by searching for the term in all the possible User fields this includes the Skill title.

my tables and relationships are in a db file this is why you will see db.Skill

```
////// db File
User.belongsToMany(Skill, {through: 'UserSkills', foreignKey: 'mentorId'});
Skill.belongsToMany(User, {through: 'UserSkills', foreignKey: 'skillId'});

////// model file
exports.learnerSearchMentors = function(req, res, term){
db.User.findAll({
where: {
$or: [

      { username       : { $like: '%' + term + '%'}},
      { firstname      : { $like: '%' + term + '%'}},
      { lastname       : { $like: '%' + term + '%'}},
      { email          : { $like: '%' + term + '%'}},
      { phone          : { $like: '%' + term + '%'}},
      { description    : { $like: '%' + term + '%'}},
      {'$skills.title$': { $like: '%' + term + '%'}}
    ]
  },
  include : [{
               model : db.Skill, {through: 'UserSkills'},
               as: 'skills'
            }]
})
.then(function(mentors){
    console.log("line 58: list of found mentors by term");
    res.status(200).send(mentors)
})
.catch(function(err){
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access included tables from parent where clause wrap column like this `$includedTable.column$`

In your case the query will look like this:

```
db.User.findAll({
  where: {
    $or: [
      {
        username: {
          $like: '%' + term + '%'
        }
      },
      ...
      { 
       '$skills.title$' : {
          $like: '%' + term + '%'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  include : [{
     model : db.Skill,
     as: 'skills'
  }]
})
.then(function(mentors){
    console.log("line 58: list of found mentors by term");
    res.status(200).send(mentors)
})
.catch(function(err){
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Tilekbekov.  I had to change the relationship this morning based on User.belongsToMany(Skill, {through: 'UserSkills', foreignKey: 'mentorId'});
Skill.belongsToMany(User, {through: 'UserSkills', foreignKey: 'skillId'}); so I have to search Skill title through a join table